# Looking for non-matched items in a collection via Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a result set from a database that I massage a bit and end up storing in a list.
Within this list, the results will look something like this:

```
Field 1: ID1
Field 2: ID2
Summary: AA
Value: 15

Field 1: ID3
Field 2: ID2
Summary: AA
Value 20

Field 1: ID1
Field 2: ID4
Summary: AA
Value 25

Field 1: ID1
Field 2: ID4
Summary: AA
Value 5

Field 1: ID1
Field 2: ID4
Summary: AB
Value 5
```

If you were to look at it from another point of view, it would look something like a grid:

```
           ID2   ID4
ID1: AA    15    30
ID1: AB           5
ID3: AA    20
```

All values that can group together (ex: ID4, ID1, Summary AA) get added together.
What I need to do is apply 0 values to the non existent data in the intersects.  So ID2/ID1/AB doesn't exist.  I need to have an item in my list to say that 'exists' but with a value of zero.
All help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have some code in your Visual Studio? Please paste it here

Comment: Possibly a case for the null coalescing operator: ?? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173224.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var items = new [] {
    new { F1 = "ID1", F2 = "ID2", S = "AA", V = 15 },
    new { F1 = "ID3", F2 = "ID2", S = "AA", V = 20 },
    new { F1 = "ID1", F2 = "ID4", S = "AA", V = 25 },
    new { F1 = "ID1", F2 = "ID4", S = "AA", V = 5  },
    new { F1 = "ID1", F2 = "ID4", S = "AB", V = 5  },
};

var f2s = items.Select(i => i.F2).Distinct();

var table =
    from i in items
    group i by new { i.F1, i.S } into g
    select new 
    { 
        g.Key, 
        V = 
            from f in f2s
            join x in g on f equals x.F2  into ps 
            from p in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { F = f, V = p != null ? p.V : 0 } into w
            group w by w.F into h
            select new { h.Key, V = h.Sum(c => c.V) }
    };
```

Comment: Why the .DefaultIfEmpty() ? It seems redundant if not passed a parameter... Or am I missing a use case?

Comment: @Flater Yes, he still wants to see the 0s explicitly, without that you would miss them. Test it in Linqpad and you'll see the difference. `DefaultIfEmpty` is not just to decide what's the default, it actually exists to generate data for the 'missing items' (in the form of default values, in this case `null`).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the coalesce operator (??).

For example:

```
string s = s2 ?? "0";
```

When s2 is null s will be "0".

See here for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx